# Acceder a web django por medio de Moodle

Tags: django, web, login, moodle

Estoy tratando de acceder a mi aplicación Django por medio de Moodle, he estado revisando 3 formas:

1. Herramienta Externa (LTI)
2. Conexión de Base de datos externa
3. URL

La más sencilla que he encontrado es por medio del recurso URL, pero el problema es que es muy insegura, es decir, todos los parámetros van en la URL y así cualquier externo encontrando los valores de los parámetros podría acceder y no es la idea.
La idea principal es poder acceder a la web django con el mismo perfil que tengo en moodle.

Saludos! y gracias por cualquier idea y ayuda!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final usé una aplicación django llamada django-lti-provider, hace que la app creada sea el proveedor de servicio a Moodle, sólo hay que seguir las instrucciones en el readme.
[Django-lti-Provider](https://github.com/ccnmtl/django-lti-provider)